# Try to make a navigation bar but something wrong

Tags: javascript, html

This is my current code. It can show where you are viewing like when you are reading "SEC 1" part, the "SEC 1" on the navigation bar gets highlighted. When you click the "SEC 2" on the navigation bar, it should jump to "SEC 2" part. **Now the problem is when you click the one you want to go, the previous one gets highlighted. For example, if you click "SEC 2", the "SEC 1" on the navigation bar gets highlighted.** As I don't know whats wrong with the code I paste it down here.

**If you don't know what's the problem:** Run the first code snippet, click the SEC 4 on the navigation bar, and then you know what's the problem: jump to SEC 4 part but highlight the SEC 3 on the navigation bar. (latest Chrome and latest Windows 10)

**The function I need:**

- Highlight the SEC- I'm currently reading on the navigation bar
- Jump to the SEC- I clicked

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<title>TEST</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
header {
    padding: 1em;
}
nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
}
nav ul li a.current {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
main {
}
section {
    padding: 5em 1em 1em 1em;
}
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5em;
    padding: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header> Header here </header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-1">SEC 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-2">SEC 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-3">SEC 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4">SEC 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="section-1">
    <h3>SEC 1</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius.</section>
  <section id="section-2">
    <h3>SEC 2</h3>
    Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Erat nam at lectus urna. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Eget magna fermentum iaculis eu. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean.</section>
  <section id="section-3">
    <h3>SEC 3</h3>
    Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Convallis tellus id interdum velit. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae. Nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi.</section>
  <section id="section-4">
    <h3>SEC 4</h3>
    Tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Amet est placerat in egestas. Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Massa massa ultricies mi quis. Volutpat sed cras ornare arcu. Varius duis at consectetur lorem. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus.</section>
</main>
<footer>Footer here</footer>
<script>
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
let mainSections = document.querySelectorAll("main section");
let lastId;
let cur = [];
window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;
  mainNavLinks.forEach(link => {
    let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
    if (
      section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
      section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
    ) {
      link.classList.add("current");
    } else {
      link.classList.remove("current");
    }
  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution by Tore Brandtzæg (Thanks! But "Currently at SEC-" function is lost)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<title>TEST</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
header {
    padding: 1em;
}
nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
}
nav ul li a.current {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
main {
}
section {
    padding: 5em 1em 1em 1em;
}
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5em;
    padding: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header> Header here </header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-1">SEC 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-2">SEC 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-3">SEC 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4">SEC 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="section-1">
    <h3>SEC 1</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean. Vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo. Consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius.</section>
  <section id="section-2">
    <h3>SEC 2</h3>
    Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Erat nam at lectus urna. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Eget magna fermentum iaculis eu. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc. Placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis. Velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt. Facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean.</section>
  <section id="section-3">
    <h3>SEC 3</h3>
    Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Et leo duis ut diam quam. Convallis tellus id interdum velit. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae. Nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. Commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi.</section>
  <section id="section-4">
    <h3>SEC 4</h3>
    Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. In pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna.<br>

Cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Praesent tristique magna sit amet.<br>

Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh. Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet. Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at. Hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus. Mi sit amet mauris commodo.</section>
</main>
<footer>Footer here</footer>
<script>
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
let clickEventListener = event => {
   mainNavLinks.forEach(link => link.classList.remove("current"));
   event.target.classList.add("current");
};
mainNavLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', clickEventListener));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like expected, tested on Firefox 71.0, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Your snippet seems to be working correctly. No problem to fix.

Comment: when your fiddle is zoomed in I cannot reproduce that bug. I assume it is because the code for your scroll is what is determining which element is active or not. you would need to add in code for the cases where the chosen element does not  scroll under your `fromTop` value.

Comment: as an aside, scroll events are a good place for someone to use [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) and depending your device requirement [intersection observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) may be preferred

Comment: Forgive me for suggesting. But it's always good to post a working code, a runnable demo so we can actually see what you mean

Comment: Actually the code is incorrect. Run the first code snippet, click the SEC 4 on the navigation bar, and then you know what's the problem: jump to SEC 4 part but highlight the SEC 3 on the navigation bar. (latest Chrome and latest Windows 10)

Comment: @Jhecht How to use that?

Comment: The links I gave are good starting points, otherwise a Google for the term(s) should yield some tutorials or examples.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits your requirements, but an alternative solution is to add a click event listener to each nav link, which deselects all other nav links and selects the one that was clicked.
This could be done by replacing the script part with something like the following:

```
let mainNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
let clickEventListener = event => {
   mainNavLinks.forEach(link => link.classList.remove("current"));
   event.target.classList.add("current");
};
mainNavLinks.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', clickEventListener));
```

At least for me, this seems to resolve the issues when clicking the links.

Edit: Just realized that you probably want the scroll functionality as well, which this solution does not include.

Comment: Your code worked, thanks for your solution! But the "current at SEC-?" function is gone.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that it does not include the selecting when scrolling functionality, so it's probably not what you want, at least not the complete functionality.

Comment: Is the original code (the first code) snippet works fine on your device? I run it and click on "SEC 4", it jumps to the SEC 4 part and highlighted the SEC 3 on the navigation bar. Also do you have solution on "currently at SEC-"?

Comment: The original code did sometimes show the incorrect selection on my device, as you described. I do not have a solution for the "currently at SEC-" functionality.